# What does "target" do?

Tags: wake

In Wake code, I know that `def` indicates something is a function. However, it looks like there is another keyword, `target` that also defines functions. For example ([taken from here](https://github.com/sifive/api-generator-sifive/blob/17efd255bb71d75a99c3025ef2fca854af25cd7a/fpga/mcs.wake#L16)):

```
global target makeBitstream plan =
  ...

global def makeMCS plan =
  ...
```

Both of these are callable from the command-line. What is the difference between `def` and `target`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just written an article about this very topic:

While the wake language is mostly functional, it is not completely pure. Wake has side-effects like running jobs and printing. It also has memoization, a contained means of storing computation described below.

Consider the Fibonacci function:

`def fib n = if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)`

Evaluating this function on 20 completes relatively quickly, but running it on 40 is another story entirely. Wake appears to run forever (really, just a very very long time).

The problem is that each invocation of fib causes two more invocations of fib. This results in a chain reaction where fib is called an exponentially increasing number of times depending on its input.

Let’s try the special target keyword:

`target fib n = if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)`

Now fib 40 completes quickly! In fact, fib 40000 also returns a result.

What has happened here is that target fib now remembers and re-uses the results of previous invocations. fib 4 will call fib 3 and fib 2. fib 3 will call fib 2 and fib 1. However, the common invocation of fib 2 now happens only once. The target remembers the result; this is called memoization.

While target is useful for speeding up toy functions, its real use is in saving work in a build system. A wake build system typically includes build rules which invoke further rules upon which they depend. Imagine job C depends on jobs B and A, but job B also depends on job A. We don’t want A to be executed twice!

Fortunately, wake’s Plan API includes by default the option to run jobs once. Internally, this API uses a target to prevent re-execution of the job. However, this use of target will not suffice in a large build.

In a large build, top-level functions which produce a Path for other functions should generally be defined using target. That way, even if the function is invoked twice by dependencies, it will only need to be evaluated once. In a build involving many targets which depend on many targets, the result can be an exponential speed-up, like we saw in the fib example.

A target can also be defined inside a function. These targets only retain their saved values while the enclosing function can access them.

`def wrappedFib n =
  target fib n = if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
  fib n`

In this example, wrappedFib uses an internal target fib to compute the Fibonacci result. However, between invocations of wrappedFib the partial results are not retained. Nested targets can be useful because they don’t consume memory for the entire execution of wake. For example, a function might need to compute a large number of uninteresting intermediate values in order to compute the value of interest (which might be saved).

One way to think about a target is that it defines a table, like in a database or a key-value map. E.g., target foo x y = z defined a table with the key Pair x y and the value z. From that point-of-view, it is perhaps unsurprising that it is sometimes useful to compute z with some inputs which are not part of the key.

target myWrite filename \ contents = write filename contents
In the above example, myWrite "file" "content" will create a file called file and fill it with the string content, returning a Path for the created file. If someone tries to write the same file with the same contents again, then the same Path will be returned.

However, what if someone tried to write the same file, but with different contents? If we allowed that, there would be a race condition in the build system! Let’s see what happens:

`$ wake -x '("bar", "bar", Nil) | map (myWrite "foo")'
Path "foo", Path "foo", Nil
$ wake -x '("bar", "baz", Nil) | map (myWrite "foo")'
ERROR: Target subkey mismatch for 'myWrite filename \ contents' (demo.wake:1:[8-34])`

In the first invocation, both calls succeed, and foo was only created once. In the second invocation, one of the calls fails with a Target subkey mismatch. These failures are fatal in wake, because it is never clear which invocation failed, due to the out-of-order parallel evaluation strategy used by wake. Nevertheless, it is probably better if a buggy build fails spectacularly, than succeeds only sporadically.

Finally, be warned of this common target gotcha:

`target foo x = match _
  None   = None
  Some y = x + y`

Normally in wake, for defines (def), the above function is the same as this:

`target foo x y = match y
  None   = None
  Some y = x + y`

However, in the target situation, these are quite different. The first target foo is memoizing a function result, while the second target foo is memoizing an Integer result (probably what was intended).